# Selenium timeout after clicking on an element but page seems to load correctly (ChromeDriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing a strange problem and I can't figure out why it is happening.

My code is written on C# and I'm using ChromeDriver

I'm clicking on an element (Actually sending SendKey(Keys.ENTER) but same problem happens when I use regular .Click())

The click seems to work OK (The element is found and I'm redirected to the page that I'm expecting (This is a complex process that runs behind with SSO)) but the code doesn't continue its execution

After some time it throws exception
  **http://localhost:7183/session/ca0fc76d263cb413b3a06f69fa5eff7e/element/0.8505282587588259-1/value timed out after 120 seconds.**

If I run the same code with FirefoxDriver or IEDriver it works OK

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of ChromeDriver? There were some issues with send keys that were fixed in 2.24.

Maybe try a js click?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I'm using 2.25.
Doesn't seem to be a problem with the SendKeys itself.

I also tried to click through Javascript code (Create a JavascriptExecutor, find the element by Xpath and click on it) and in that case the click works OK and continues the execution but on the next sentence that I need to use the same WebDriver, it fails again to timeout

Comment: I have used the js click also when seeing odd behavior like this. Can you post the html and the click/xpath code? If you debug it, does it work fine? I was wondering about waits or if this was possibly an iframe.

Comment: The HTML is kind of complex

Comment: The HTML is kind of complex and is a third party page that we use so I don't know the details of what is the code behind it but basically the structure is a form and inside different buttons

I use an XPATH like this 

//form//button[text()[contains(.,'foo')]]

Because I need to locate the button according to its text, and then I click on it

The click seems to work OK and the browser behaves as expected but the code doesn't continue and after some time I get a timeout

Comment: If you change it to a js click what happens?  I have seen issues with c# clicks and I have used a js click instead.  Added the code to the answer. I would debug it though and see where it is exactly failing. You may need to change your xpath a bit or maybe add a move to element.

Comment: If I simply click through JavaScript it happens the same

Someone at work helped me to try clicking through JavaScript like this


`script = @"var tmpElm = /*Here I get the element through XPATH*/ (function() { tmpElm.click(); }, 0);";
js.ExecuteScript(script);`


When I do it this way it clicks and continues with the execution (Which seems OK) but in the next sentence that I have to use the WebDriver then it also throws a timeout exception on doing something else (Not related !!!)

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is run it through debugger and step through the code and see exactly where it is failing and what it can't find. If it can't find the element, why?

Comment: I debug it but it doesn't seem to me that it can't find an element, (If it was the case the exception would be Could not find that element as it usually does)

It just stays on a sentence and then just throws a timeout exception, that's why I'm so lost

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I set this timeout manager in the ChromeDriver execution, now it will wait 60 secs before gets the timeout error.  `driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);`